# GROUP_CONCAT() behaving differently on Oracle Enterprise LINUX

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have written a MySQL query to get all user ids in a comma separated list:

```
select group_concat(USER_ID) from T_USER
```

the result is as expected.

But the same is not working if executed in the SQL developer. I connected the MySQL Production DB in Oracle SQL developer tool.

[image]

Oracle SQL Developer:

[image]

Comment: Yes @Ageonix As MySql was installed on Oracle Enterprise Linux

Comment: It looks like Orcale sql developer tool issue, try [MySQL workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) - it's very nice to work with MySQL.

Comment: I am connecting MySql from Nodejs but still it gives same result.